# Looking for ASP.NET ( MVC 3 ) forum engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forum

I am looking for forum engine.

There are some requirements:

1. platform is ASP.NET(MVC 2,3)
2. MS SQL or MySql database
3. Open source
4. Customizeable (change theme, moderator settings, account settings etc.)
5. High performance

Could somebody advice most applicable solution?

Comment: I just wrote a blog about that, which contains 17 different MVC based forums, a few of which do match your requirements. Take a look at it here: http://digioz.blogspot.com/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-forum-software.html Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nearforums](http://nearforums.codeplex.com/) is ASP.NET MVC 3 forum, with MSSQL and MySql engine support.

MIT (permissive) licensed, web administration, templates (aka themes), I18n, ... is delivered by the [Outercurve Foundation](http://www.outercurve.org/).

Answer (score 9):

Also have a look at..

http://www.mvcforum.com

Unity, DDD, Entity Framework v5, MVC3, SQL EXPRESS and open source.

Comment: Why not come on the forum and tell us why? I've only had positive comments, I'd like to know your issues?

Comment: how can implement MVCForum on Existing site ? or  any Documentation  for Integration Existing Site?